# Sitecore 8 Path Analyser -PathMap is null

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I've installed a new Sitecore 8 instance, setup a MongoDB instance and started it running.

I've deployed the analytics definitions.

When I go to The Path Analyser I get the following Error.

*There was an error loading data, please try again. PathExplorer.PathMapDataLoaded() - PathMap is null.*

Any idea what might be wrong? Any other steps I need to perform?

Comment: Found an error in the log file: ERROR No tree exists for the given tree definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged this with support - This has been reported as a bug.